# How many $4$-letter codes with two vowels and two consonants can be formed by using the letters of the word QUESTION only once?

Tags: combinatorics

If you were allowed to use a letter from the word "QUESTION" only once, how many 4-letter codes formed containing two vowels and two consonants?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  When you pose a question here, it is expected that you include your own thoughts on the problem.  For an exercise such as this, you should indicate what you have attempted and where you are stuck so that you receive responses appropriate to your skill level.

Comment: I think you mean, how many **code words** can be formed.

Answer (score 1):

We have $4$ vowels and $4$ consonants. We want two from each set, and then rearrangements, so:

$$\binom{4}{2}^2\cdot4!=36\cdot24=864$$

Comment: How is that possible, sir? It is not in the choices that are given to me. 24, 144, 1728, and 3456 are the choices.

Comment: we are counting words like QUES, SQUE, TIQO, etc. ?

Comment: Uh-huh. 4-letter codes. Can it be 1728?

Comment: i can't see how to get an extra factor of 2. it could be 144 in that we must have VVCC, so 36.4

Comment: Please, show me how to get 144

Comment: Poker is played using 5 cards to form a hand from a standard deck of 52 cards. A full house is a hand that contains a three-of-a-kind and a two-of-a-kind. How many ways can a full house be formed?

Comment: EUQS, EUSQ, UEQS, UESQ, vowel combinations are 2 from UEIO, so UE, UI, UO, EI, EO, IO, consonants from QSTN, so QS, QT, QN, ST, SN, TN. giving 6*6*4=144. your poker question is a different question.